# How to rediret to custom error page if some words are addeded in the URL after extention?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am working on an DNN project i am facing a problem 
For i have following URL http //test/EN/Concept/Informationsystems.aspx
and there some user put any thing wrong in the url but before the .aspx extension it redirects
to correct error page that is set in through web config.
But the problem i am facing is that if some user type wrong url through adding and words ahead of .aspx extension 
like the above same url is mistyped like
http ://test/EN/Concept/Informationsystems.aspx**qeqwewqeqwe** then it redirects to IIS error page but i want it to redirect to the the same error page that i set in the web config. 
How can i do it please suggest me the setting require.

Answer (score 1):

Add tag in config file this

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">
  <!--404 error code is for resource not found -->
  <error statusCode ="404"  redirect="Error.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: No this not my problem, i set the error page same as you told, but if somebody types some after the aspx extension, it redirects to IIS error page rather than the custom error page i set.

Answer (score 1):

for status specific custom page , you can extend customErrors like this.

So just check which error status code is given by IIS and write code accordingly e.g.

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

Add this code under  in the web.config file

```
httpErrors

  remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" 

  error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="" responseMode="ExecuteURL"   

httpErrors
```

in the path specify your custom error page. please check the syntax.

I hope this will help you...